# Confidence value of Tesseract OCR

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I have some questions about Tesseract OCR confidence value which can be obtained by calling `AllWordConfidences()` function in C++ API.

1. What is the confidence value (returned by tesseract API) and **how tesseract calculates that value?** (like based on what factors)?
2. Is there any possibility that I can change the accuracy levels of tesseract?

Can anyone help me with these questions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used similar metrics in other OCR software (specifically in ANPR software).  If I recall correctly there are two confidence factors overall; one is a 0->100% confidence factor and the other is a 0->X value that is used as an aggregation of the various cascading confidence factors.
This value is arbitrary and so I'd recommend using the 0->100% value.  Also note that each character should have a confidence factor.

These metrics calculated by evaluating how clear contour lines/edges are, how close the shapes detected in characters are to expected shapes and how close the decisions are to choose one character vs another is. IE the OCR has an easier time choosing between 'p' and 'b' than 'Q' and 'O'.

The only way to 'improve' these metrics is to train the detector!  So prepare to have lots of valid data.  You will also need patience using the Tesseract training tools - I found them to be 75% nightmarish.

Good luck!